# Encourage users to Like/Dislike proposals

Tags: website-design, web-app, e-commerce, checkout

I am working on a marketplace for which clients get constant proposals from service providers. The proposals usually include an image, description and price. A large number of the clients browse through the proposals list, but take no action regarding them. What could be appropriate ways to encourage clients to like/dislike the proposals?

For us taking an action is one step closer to the checkout funnel. Also Liking/disliking helps other service providers fine tune future proposals, allowing clients to being closer to receiving the perfect proposal.

Comment: Does liking/disliking actually improve future proposals that the client sees? E.g.., does it act like the Netflix rating system where it suggests shows you might like based on shows you've previously rated highly? If not, that's probably where you should start. If so, then you might need to make that personalization more obvious. "You liked that proposal. You might also like these..." The clients need to see some value returned for their effort in up or down proposals. The more immediate, the better.

Comment: You could include a point system such as stackexchange does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one thing I've learned from Reddit, Yik Yak, Stack Exchange, and any other platform with visible metadata: **scores increase engagement.**

You receive no significant incentive from participating, other than a number—yet psychologically we want to beat others. As long as it fits your platform, this might be a great way to increase involvement.

Answer (score 0):

- You can say you are planning to make **promotions** for some articles and you need to know which one they want to be promoted, and ask them to vote for it.
- The better way to encourage clients to like/dislike the proposals may be to ask them **during waiting time**. If they have nothing to do, they would probably enjoy to use their wasted time to fill a survey.